# Using an Include on an ICollection in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5

Here's a sample of my data model:

```
class Invoice
{
    public ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

class LineItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can eager load LineItem like so:

```
return DataContext.Invoices.First().Include("LineItems.Category");
```

How can I do this using a Lambda?

```
return DataContext.Invoices.First().Include(li => li.LineItems); //I can't chain any more includes since LineItems is an ICollection
```

**Edit**:
I tried

```
return DataContext.Invoices.Include(i => i.LineItems.First().Category).Single();
```

and it resulted in an `ArgumentException` with the following message:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the following and it seems to have worked properly:

```
return DataContext.Invoices.Include(i => i.LineItems.Select(li => li.Category)).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return DataContext.Invoices.Include(li => li.LineItems).First();
```

Comment: Please explain why this would work and what the OP tried did not.

Comment: I think maybe what Daniel meant was to put the First() on the LineItems, which isn't really all that far off from what worked.